# fitting svm model errorValueError: could not convert string to float: '[array([0.30067509, 0.11679184, 0.01250501, and so on

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

```
import pickle

from sklearn import svm

from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

import numpy

def train_svm(features, labels, reg_param, kernel_type):

    clf = svm.SVC(C = reg_param, kernel = kernel_type)

    svm_model = clf.fit(features, labels)

    print("fitting model done!")

    return svm_model


features_of_images = pickle.load(open("/Users/15195/Desktop/ece613/ped_features.p", 'rb'))

labels_of_images = pickle.load(open("/Users/15195/Desktop/ece613/peds_feature_to_label.p", 'rb'))

svm_model = train_svm(features_of_images, labels_of_images, 0.01,'linear')

pickle.dump(svm_model, open("/Users/15195/Desktop/ece613/trained_svm_model.p", 'wb'))
```

Comment: which line raises the error?

Comment: also what is the shape of `features_of_images ` ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your pickle files are saved as string, not as float array. SKlearn is trying to use the string as a float array, yet it fails, as your string is : ["array([0.30067509, 0.11679184, 0.01250501 ..

It looks like you had a list of features as float array but failed to pickle it.

Therefore, it would be better to see pickling part as well. And more information about your settings can be helpful